# jquery add remove form input on toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following `html` and `form` elements

```
<div class='ticket-sold' id='1' >RAFFLE-1-NOVEMBER</div>
<div class='ticket' id='2'>RAFFLE-2-NOVEMBER</div>
<div class='ticket' id='3'>RAFFLE-3-NOVEMBER</div>
<div class='ticket' id='4'>RAFFLE-4-NOVEMBER</div>
<div class='ticket' id='5'>RAFFLE-5-NOVEMBER</div>

<form class="paypal" action="./includes/gateways/payments.php" method="post" id="paypal_form" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="UK" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
    <input type="hidden" name="payer_email" value="customer@example.com"  />
   <input name="item_name_1" value="TICKET NUMBER 5" id="input_5" type="hidden">
   <input name="item_name_2" value="TICKET NUMBER 20" id="input_20" type="hidden">
   <input name="item_name_3" value="TICKET NUMBER 27" id="input_27" type="hidden">
   <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="10" id="input_5" />
   <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="10" id="input_20" />
   <input type="hidden" name="amount_3" value="10" id="input_27" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Payment"/>
</form>
```

Basically, I have jquery that when the Div class 'ticket' is selected, the 'amount' field is updated based on the number of 'ticket' elements selected.

```
var counter = 0;
$(".ticket").on("click", function() {
$(this).toggleClass("green");
$(this).toggleClass('selected');
var selectedIds = $('.selected').map(function() {
        return this.id;
}).get();
var id = $(this).attr('id');  
if(!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
    $('#paypal_form #input_' + id).remove();
    counter--;
} else {
    counter++;
    $('#paypal_form').append('<input type="hidden" name="item_name_'+counter+'" value="TICKET NUMBER ' + id + '" id="input_'+id+'">');
    $('#paypal_form').append('<input type="hidden" name="amount_'+counter+'" value="' + $(".ticketprice").text() +'" id="input_'+id +'">');
    }   
    $(".totaltickets").text(selectedIds.length -1);
    $(".totalprice").text((selectedIds.length - 1)*$(".ticketprice").text());
```

What I would like to do, is at the same time of the onclick function on the 'ticket' div, I would like another input type ie `<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Selected ID from Div">` added dynamically to the Form ("paypal_form").  And if the 'ticket' DIV is toggled, ie Clicked to deselect the item, the added  element should be removed.

thanks
Craig.

Answer (score 0):

You could approach it similar to this. It checks if the class `selected` is assigned to the selected div. If so, it appends a hidden input with a specific ID to the form. If the div is unselected, it removes that input from the form.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ticket").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("green");
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    
    var selectedIds = $('.selected').map(function() {
      return this.id;
    }).get();
    
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    
    if(!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      $('#paypal_form #input_' + id).remove();
    } else {
      $('#paypal_form').append('<input type="hidden" id="input_' + id + '">');
    }
    
    $('[name=amount]').val((selectedIds.length - 1) * $(".ticketprice").text());
    $('[name=item_name]').val((selectedIds.length - 1) + " Ticket(s) selected");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='ticket-sold' id='1'>RAFFLE-1-NOVEMBER</div>
<div class='ticket' id='2'>RAFFLE-2-NOVEMBER</div>
<div class='ticket' id='3'>RAFFLE-3-NOVEMBER</div>
<div class='ticket' id='4'>RAFFLE-4-NOVEMBER</div>
<div class='ticket' id='5'>RAFFLE-5-NOVEMBER</div>

<form class="paypal" action="./includes/gateways/payments.php" method="post" id="paypal_form" target="_blank">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
  <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="UK" />
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
  <input type="hidden" name="payer_email" value="customer@example.com" />
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Payment" />
</form>
```

Comment: thanks, but the .remove function doesnt remove the line from the form.

$('#paypal_form #input_' + id).remove();

Comment: @CraigJohnstone -- Did you try to run the code snippet in StackOverflow itself? It is working absolutely fine.

Comment: hi, I've updated the original post above with the updates you suggested.. it nearly works.. although when I remove the middle item it doesnt re-order the numbering correctly.

Comment: @CraigJohnstone -- is ordering really necessary. It really doesn't matter to the server that in which order you're supplying the parameters.

Comment: paypal cart requires all items to be ordered 1 - whatever.. ie  item_1, item_2 etc etc.. I tried just using the ticket no.  ie item_20, item_27 but it fails to process at the paypal end.

Comment: Ifigured it out with the following

var ii = 1;
   $("input[name^='item_name']").each(function(i){
    $(this).attr('name', 'item_name_' + ii++);
   });
   var ii = 1;
   $("input[name^='amount']").each(function(i){
    $(this).attr('name','amount_' + ii++);
   });

thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

figured it out with the following

```
var ii = 1; 
$("input[name^='item_name']").each(function(i){ 
    $(this).attr('name', 'item_name_' + ii++); 
}); 
var ii = 1; 
$("input[name^='amount']").each(function(i){ 
    $(this).attr('name','amount_' + ii++); 
});
```

thanks for your help :)